# Repeat Alerts not working on the iphone 5

Tags: user-account

Why doesn't the repeat alerts work on the iphone 5 for text messages? After the initial alert. It doesn't make any sounds to notify that you have an unread text despite me setting it to remind me up to 10 times in the notification center.

Comment: As far as I can find, this is not a common or known bug in iOS 6 or on the iPhone 5.  Have you tried the basics of power cycling and/or resetting (press and hold sleep/wake and Home button until you see the apple logo) the device?  If so, can you give us some more information?  Which version of iOS 6 are you running, are you using custom alert tones or vibration setting? Does it work on any of the other setting intervals besides 10?  Also, the alerts repeat on 2 minute intervals so if you're sitting there waiting for it, it can seem like a while.

Answer (score 1):

Just got my iPhone 5 2 days ago and noticed this as well.  Was on iOS 6.0.1 have since upgraded to 6.0.2 and same issue.

I've noticed if I leave a particular persons text messages up, I do not get another notification.  However, if I press the home screen and go back to the main screen I'll then receive audible notifications.

I did restore from my iPhone 4S backup via iTunes.  Later today I'm going to wipe the phone and rebuild from scratch and see if that helps.

Comment: Could you perhaps explain _why_ wiping might help - this isn't really an answer to the question and too long to turn into a comment, but I believe you might be able to add more details to turn this into an answer - even if it's not 100% the problem being seen - it could help others understand how this works and how to troubleshoot notifications.